# $\ln(1+x)\underset{x\to 0}{=} \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{x^{k}}{k}+o(x^{n})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

> I would like to see the setps behind that implication
>   $$
> \frac{1}{1+x}\underset{x\to 0}{=} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}x^{k}+o(x^{n-1})
> \implies
> \ln(1+x)\underset{x\to 0}{=} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{x^{k}}{k}+o(x^{n})
> $$

**My Thoughts**

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+x}&\underset{x\to 0}{=} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}x^{k}+o(x^{n-1})\\
\text{Primitive, knowing that }\ln(1)=0 \\
\ln(1+x)&\underset{x\to 0}{=} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}+o(\frac{x^{n}}{n})\\
\ln(1+x)&\underset{x\to 0}{=} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}+o(x^{n})&\text{By operations over Little-Oh}\\
\end{align}

Let $ t=k+1$ when $k = 0 \implies t=1$ and when  $k = n-1 \implies t=n$ and $k=t-1$ then   \begin{align}
\ln(1+x)&\underset{x\to 0}{=} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}+o(x^{n})\\
\ln(1+x)&\underset{x\to 0}{=} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^{k}}{k}+o(x^{n})
\end{align}

- This contradicts the result that I have to find, can you correct me where I have made the mistake?

i just missed that $$(-1)^{k-1}=(-1)^{k+1} $$

indeed
$$(-1)^{k-1}=(-1)^{k}\times(-1)^{-1}=(-1)^k\times\frac1{(-1)}=(-1)^k\times(-1)=(-1)^{k+1}.$$

- So i have question why we have to work with $k+1$ instead of $k-1$ since they are equal

Comment: @NormalHuman  i fixed it

Comment: There is no contradiction: $k-1$ and $k+1$ have the same parity.

Comment: but how can i achieve the same resultat

Comment: What do you mean? How to obtain $(-1)^{k+1}$? Just replace  $(-1)^{k-1}$ with   $(-1)^{k+1}$.

Comment: @Bernard  that's all ???

Comment: please is there any lectures or document online talk about that i should read it to refresh my memory Thanks

Comment: Absolutely. Why do it the hard way when it can be done the easy way? ;o)

Comment: I don't know. Fundamentally, your approach is quite fine. It's only this final  detail you've missed.

Comment: yes i missed it because i didn't aware of it that's why i need some document to see it thanks

Comment: I'm afraid there's no specific document. It's only a matter of practice.

Comment: $(-1)^{k-1}=(-1)^{k}\times(-1)^{-1}=(-1)^k\times\frac1{(-1)}=(-1)^k\times(-1)=(-1)^{k+1}.$

Comment: Simpler:$(-1)^{k+1}=(-1)^{k-1+2}=(-1)^{k-1}(-1)^2=(-1)^{k-1}$.